# Symfony return a response to export excel

Tags: excel, symfony

How do I return a response in Symfony that will output an excel file? I am getting an error that I must return a response and it needs to be in a string correct? Help!

```
 $excel = new PHPExcel();

 $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $excel->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'hi');

 $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel2007');
 $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

 return $objWriter;
```

Error:

> The controller must return a response (Object(PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007) given).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Controller must return an instance of `Response` class, so do the following:

```
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');

return new Response(
    ob_get_clean(),  // read from output buffer
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="doc.xls"',
    )
);
```

If you use Excel 2007 or upper set content type to `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"` and file extension to `xlsx`.

Comment: this is giving me a page with gibberish characters.

Comment: @StormParker Yes, I was wrong with the returning method. You may use the solution from the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've got a route and a controller to export an XLS generated (in my case a button access the route and returns the XLS file)

Also, I read a already generated and stored file, but it should work even if you're not storing the file, you should just use the `$objWriter;` in this line

```
$response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedResponse($writer);
```

Also, I'm not using the Response object that VisioN indicated I should.

The Action:

```
public function exportAction() {
    $readerObject = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
    $phpExcelObject = $readerObject->load('files/downloads/reports/' . $this->getUser()->getName() . '.xls');
    $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel5');
    $response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedResponse($writer);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=' . $this->getUser()->getName() . '.xls');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');

    return $response;
}
```

Please note, `'Excel5'` is for XLS files, if you desire XLSX files you should replace those with `'Excel2007'`

Comment: FYI There is a `$this->getUser()` shortcut method.

Comment: Happy now? I don't see how it's relevant to the user's question.

Comment: That doesn't releate to the question at all. I wrote *FYI*, which means *"For Your Information"*: it doesn't state that you should use the proposed way, just to keep in mind that there is a shorter alternative.

Comment: use 'application/vnd.ms-excel' and not 'text/vnd.ms-excel', which does not exist.
( full list of mimetypes: https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml#L1898 )